# SvelteKit: Pass Data From +Layout.svelte To +page.svelte SPA (static) application

Tags: single-page-application, sveltekit

I'm struggling with the latest version of SvelteKit, the docs available only works with SSR, and I'm developing a SPA (static page), so, what is the way to pass data from my `+layout.svelte` to `+page.svelte` ?.

The documentation says that with load function from `+page.js` (I've already set `export const ssr=false`, and I understood that `+page.js` is for SSR), but that doesn't work in SPA mode, and if I have the `load` function from the layout it's seems not to work.

Additionaly I want to trigger a function from my `+page.svelte` that is in the layout page.

Any ideas?

Here is what I tried :

```html
<!-- +layout.svelte -->
<script>
    export function load() {
        return {
            data: { title: 'default title' }
        };
    }
    export let data;
</script>

//+page.svelte
<script>
    export let data;
    console.log(data.title); //undefined
</script>
```

The documentation says not to use : `<script context="module">`, and I don't want to use the store because I think there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load functions belong in the accompanying files `+layout.js`/`ts`, not on the page. They also do not return a property data, everything returned is the data. See [the docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#layout-data).

If SSR is disabled, you can event return a store that could be modified from the page.

To get a store from the data so it can be used with `$`-syntax, the `data` property can be destructured on the page:

```js
export let data;
$: ({ title } = data);
```

---

You could also create a store and set it as a [context](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-setcontext) in the layout. Pages then can get said context and interact with it. This allows two-way interaction.

Using a store is necessary if the contents require reactivity (i.e. are changed) and the page or layout needs to update.

Comment: thanks, but, in a SPA app, how do I should to pass data between layout and page?

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. The same mechanism should be usable anywhere, `load` is executed on server or client.

Comment: If you mean that you are creating a static site, that is an entirely separate thing.

Comment: yes, is a static site, I will deploy that page in a S3 bucket

Comment: I included my original answer again, because the same mechanism works even for static sites. The load function will simply only execute in the browser, it is completely independent from SSR.